# Helm chart & docker image version management

Tags: kubernetes-helm

We have around 50 micro services. Each micro service has its own repo in git. And in its repo we have a chart folder for the helm chart.

We also have an umbrella chart/parent chart for those 50 sub charts.

To differentiate dev, qa, production helm packages. We used different name for the umbrella chart and different versioning.

For example, all our development charts all have versions like version 0.0.0.xxxxx and production charts all have versions like 1.0.0.xxxxx.

The purpose of the different versioning strategy is so that we can pull down sub charts from different branches when building the parent chart.

When we run the pipeline from development branch, it will create helm chart with version prefix `0.0.0`, and when from master branch, it creates chart version with prefix `1.0.0`. And to make it simple, we are not using `AppVersion`, on `Chart version` and every time we build a new docker image, we bump up the Chart version.
For example, we have the following `requirements.yaml` in our development parent chart.

```
dependencies:
- name: subchart1
  repository: 'chartmuseum'
  version: ~0.0.0
- name: subchart2
  repository: 'chartmusuem'
  version: ~0.0.0
```

With this, when we run the pipeline of the development parent chart, it will pull down the dependencies that are built from development branch.
This works well.

The first problem we are having now is when multiple developers work on different micro services, they would include each other's changes when building the parent chart.

The second problem is with updating the sub charts. The yaml templates of all the charts are very similar(deployment, configmap, ingress). Sometimes, when we need to update an ingress setting for all the charts, we have to go to different git repos to update them and merge them to different branches. I am now considering creating one single dedicated git repo for all the charts. But I would like to hear some advice on the management of Chart. What are the best practices for managing helm charts and docker repositories in large scale.

Comment: do you manually fill sub chart version in umbrella, or automatically update umbrella when building sub chart? please clarify in the question.

Comment: @LeiYang No, chart version is filled by our pipeline.

Comment: @laocius Do we have any other update on your issue? I do have some similar context, where our multiple helm charts are residing a single git repo and we have deployment pipeline from there. Would love to hear about how you overcome on this.